# Using the single purpose aggregation of group in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to solve this problem: Using the single purpose aggregation operation of group, group the documents by AgencyName to count the number of occurrences of each event per AgencyName. Print each AgencyName and its count.

This is my approach:

```
db.HW6.group( 
{ key: 
  { 
  AgencyName: "$AgencyName" },    
  reduce: function( curr, result) { result.count += 1},    
  initial: { count: 0 } 
})
```

I am getting some odd results, and I am not sure why. It could just be the structure of the data, but I haven't received odd results like these yet. Does it look like my syntax is correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please show your document with the expected result?